# I want a div of specific height to grow in width as necessary to accommodate text

Tags: css, flexbox

As shown in the example bellow, I want a div of specific height to grow in width only as much as necessary to accommodate it's text, but I can't do it

I want it to look like this

[image]

```css
body{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: max-content;
  
  
}

.item{
  
  width: min-content ;
  max-height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container" >
  <div class="item"> sid jkodasjkadf kadsf kas</div>
  <div class="item"> salkf hjahsadkjhfgadsakjsl</div>
  <div class="item"> saf nasd kmfgdn skjdsj</div>
  <div class="item"> sjfn sdnf sdmfosdj md faikmoa fia</div>
  <div class="item"> siiojasd oiasdi </div>
  <div class="item"> alksj fksdafja</div>
  <div class="item"> sid jkodas jkadf kadsf kas</div>
  <div class="item"> salkf hjahsadkjhfga dsakjsl</div>
  <div class="item"> saf nasd kmfgdn skjdsj</div>
  <div class="item"> sjfn sdnf sdmfosdj md faikmoa fia</div>
  <div class="item"> siiojasd oiasdi </div>
  <div class="item"> alksj fksdafja</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I want the item div to have a dynamic width to fit the text inside them. At the same time I want the div to have a fixed height.

Comment: I added a picture, hope this makes more sense @Paulie_D

Comment: You can't do that with a fixed height and width of min-content. Pick one or the other,

Comment: @Paulie_D do you know any way of doing it?

Comment: No, at best you will need javascript but that's not the way text lays out. Either it wraps at a determined width or it doesn't and you just get a single line.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
}

.item{
  max-height: 3em;
  border: 4px solid red;
  padding:1rem;
}
```